# Rails - validate child object with existing parent resource data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the proper procedure of validating a new child object using data from the existing parent resource? I don't understand how to access the parent resource's data from the child model.

Context: My child model `Reservation` has a date range attribute that can't conflict/overlap with other `Reservation` objects of the parent object. The way I'm trying to accomplish this is to write a custom validator in the `Reservation` model that pulls all existing Reservations of the parent object and iterates through them, ensuring that there is no conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with a custom validator and iterating over the reservations sounds good to me.

Assuming you've got this:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

then you can use reservation.parent.reservations in order to iterate over the existing reservations.